# Using protobuf with MPI for new datatype?

Tags: mpi, protocol-buffers

Usaully, one would have to define a new type and register it with MPI to use it. I am wondering if using protobuf to serialize a object and send it over using MPI as byte stream. I have two questions:
(1) do you foresee any problem with this approach?
(2) do I need to send length information through a separate `MPI_Send()`, or can I probe and use `MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_BYTE, &count)`?

An example would be:

```
        // sender 
        MyObj myobj; 
        ...
        size_t size = myobj.ByteSizeLong();
        void *buf = malloc(size);
        myobj.SerializePartialToArray(buf, size);
        MPI_Isend(buf, size, MPI_BYTE, ... )
        ...

        // receiver
        MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &status);
        if (flag) {
            MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_BYTE, &size);
            MPI_Recv(buf, size, MPI_BYTE, ... , &status);
            MyObject obj;
            obj.ParseFromArray(buf, size);
            ...

        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MPI is message oriented, you should be OK. Mixing protobuf and MPI might upset a purist, but I wouldn't let that hold you back!

Comment: You can also consider extensions such as BoostMPI or mpi4py if you are developing in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can do that. Your code sketch looks also fine (except for the omitted `buf` allocation on the receiver side). As Gilles points out, makes sure to use `status.MPI_SOURCE` and `status.MPI_TAG` for the actual `MPI_Recv`, not `MPI_*_ANY`.

However, there are some performance limitations.

1. Protobuf isn't very fast, particularly due to en-/decoding. It very much depends what your performance expectations are. If you run on a high performance network, assume a significant impact. Here are [some basic benchmarks](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_benchmarks.html).
2. Not knowing the message size ahead and thus always posting the receive after the send also has performance implications. This means the actual transmission will likely start later, which may or may not have an impact on the senders side since you are using non-blocking sends. There could be cases, where you run into some practical limitations regarding number of unexpected messages. That is not a general correctness issues, but might require some configuration tuning.

If you go ahead with your approach, remember to do some performance analysis on the implementation. Use an MPI-aware performance analysis tool to make sure your approach doesn't introduce critical bottlenecks.

Comment: You also need to make sure you `MPI_Recv()` with the source *returned* by the previous `MPI_Iprobe()` otherwise you might receive the message from a different rank and a different size.

Comment: strictly speaking, since `MPI_ANY_TAG` was used in `MPI_Iprobe()`, I think `MPI_ANY_TAG` can be used too in `MPI_Recv()`. The rationale is messages from a given rank are received in the order they were sent. Conversely, there is no global ordering (regarding messages sent by different ranks), so `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` cannot be used in `MPI_Recv()`. Makes sense ?